Apache Solr healthcheck giving ERROR: 401 require authentication
I am using Apache Solr 9.5.0. When I do healthcheck using:
solr/bib/solr run_tool healthcheck -zkHost "$ZK_HOST" -collection "$HEALTHCHECK_COLLECTION" $VERBOSE

I get below error:
-- RECENT
{collection_name}
INFO  - 2024-12-18 12:32:04.867; org.apache.solr.util.configuration.SSLConfigurations; Setting javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
INFO  - 2024-12-18 12:32:04.873; org.apache.solr.util.configuration.SSLConfigurations; Setting javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword

ERROR: Error from server at https://localhost:25103/solr/dev-audit-2024_shard1_replica_n1/select?q=*%3A*&rows=0&_stateVer_=dev-audit-2024%3A111&wt=javabin&version=2: Expected mime type in [application/vnd.apache.solr.javabin, application/octet-stream] but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 require authentication</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 require authentication</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/dev-audit-2024_shard1_replica_n1/select</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>require authentication</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

I have below configurations:
security.json
    {
    "authentication":{
     "class":"solr.CertAuthPlugin",
     "credentials":{"gmpsolr":"encrypted password"}
    },
    "authorization":{
     "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
     "user-role":{"gmpsolr":"admin"},
     "permissions":[{"name":"all",
     "role":"admin"}]
    }}

Arguments set as below:
    -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks
    -DSTOP.PORT=24103
    -DdisableAdminUI=false
    -Dhost=10.0.2.15
    -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/......../solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/......../solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
    -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    -Djdk.xml.xpathExprGrpLimit=0
    -Djdk.xml.xpathExprOpLimit=0
    -Djdk.xml.xpathTotalOpLimit=0
    -Djetty.home=/......../solr-9.5.0/server
    -Djetty.port=25103
    -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
    -Dsolr.default.confdir=/......./solr-9.5.0/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf
    -Dsolr.http1=true
    -Dsolr.install.dir=/......./solr-9.5.0
    -Dsolr.install.symDir=/......./solr
    -Dsolr.jetty.host=0.0.0.0
    -Dsolr.jetty.https.port=25103
    -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.excludes=
    -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.includes=
    -Dsolr.jetty.keystore.type=JKS
    -Dsolr.jetty.keystore=/......./solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
    -Dsolr.jetty.ssl.needClientAuth=false
    -Dsolr.jetty.ssl.wantClientAuth=false
    -Dsolr.jetty.truststore.type=JKS
    -Dsolr.jetty.truststore=/......./solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
    -Dsolr.keyStoreReload.enabled=true
    -Dsolr.log.dir=/......./log
    -Dsolr.log.muteconsole
    -Dsolr.max.booleanClauses=10000
    -Dsolr.modules=scripting
    -Dsolr.solr.home=/......./dbs/recentNode
    -Dsolr.zk.embedded.host=0.0.0.0
    -Duser.timezone=UTC
    -DzkClientTimeout=30000

Also the curl command is working as expected:
curl -u gmpsolr:password -k https://localhost:25103/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS

Is there anything that I missed?

Have you provided the relevant authentication information to the bin/solr script as shown in the reference manual? https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/basic-authentication-plugin.html#using-the-solr-control-script-with-basic-auth

post adding the below in solr.in.sh it worked
SOLR_AUTH_TYPE="basic"
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"
but is there a way we can use encrypted password, as it sill be stored in plain text in solr.in.sh file?

The client needs to be able to read it and decrypt it, so storing it encrypted won't really give you much (the part in the configuration file isn't encrypted, it's hashed) - you can provide it on the command line instead of storing it in a file if you want to, or you can set is an environment variable that gets decrypted on login (with a given password) to avoid storing it in plaintext on disk
